# Hiring a virtual server

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualhost, virtual-machines

I'm looking to hire a virtual server to host the sites of my clients.
Is that possible? I can host as many sites as I want in a virtual server?

Does anyone know please tell me where I can find virtual server for a good price.

Comment: Cause of your "basic" questions I would advice you to look for a managed server (in this case linux is always cheaper than windows), instead of try and fail with a rootserver on your own. Of course if you want to learn (with a LOCAL machine first) managing a server I'm sure you're at the right place here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good sites for discussing specific hosting provider/server specification scenarios](http://serverfault.com/questions/292013/good-sites-for-discussing-specific-hosting-provider-server-specification-scenari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rent a VPS (Virtual Private Server) and put some sites on them. The number of sites you can put on one VPS will depend on the size, RAM, CPU, ... the VPS has. There are many VPS providers around the world. So, you should probably get one that is as close to you as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your first question is yes. The second question is most likely a no but how many you can host would depend on the load that each of the client sites puts on the server.

As for where you can get a server at a good price you'll have to do your own research as we don't generally do [**shopping**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Virtual Private Server (VPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). A lot of host providers have VPS options, but these will vary based on OS, memory, disk space, etc.  It is also important to know the location of the VPS, which varies from host to host.

"Cloud hosting" is another option to look into, especially if you will be running different sites in a single location.

I've used the following VPS, all with roughly the same performance:

[1&1 hosting](http://order.1and1.com/links/virtual-servers.html)
 [SolarVPS](http://www.solarvps.com/)
 [SliceHost](http://www.slicehost.com/)

As for some "cloud" options, if you'd like to be on the cutting edge with less systems work than a VPS:

[Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/) has been reliable, but a little pricy.
  [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) recently had a major failure, but recovering. Lesson here is "backup your data."
  [Microsoft Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/)